# Can Flutter access native iOS Screen Time API?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

new to flutter. Can Flutter access native iOS APIs such as the screentime api?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/deviceactivity/deviceactivitydata

Answer (score 1):

Communication to native part is done over platform channels.

> The Flutter portion of the app sends messages to its host, the non-Dart portion of the app, over a platform channel. The host listens on the platform channel, and receives the message. It then calls into any number of platform-specific APIs—using the native programming language—and sends a response back to the client, the Flutter portion of the app.

See [Writing custom platform-specific code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) for details.